# Jupyter kernel crashing when executing an RNN fitting

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

After loading and cleaning the dataset in the Jupyter notebook, I tried to run  following code:

```
#Fitting the RNN to the Training set
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 100, batch_size = 32)
```

The output is:

```
Epoch 1/100
```

Any of the previous operation give me problems, including adding 4 LSTM layers, the output layer and compiling the RNN.

And then the kernel stops working and I can't go on.

Any suggestion or a way to understand what is going wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved.
The dataset was too large for my local memory (around 3.5 million entries, lol).
I'd to split it in smaller chunks!